# Whether the vector is linearly dependent or independete?

Tags: linear-algebra

Whether the vector is linearly dependent or independete?

{1 +2 x ²-x, 2-x +3 x ², 3-4x +7 x ² C p2}

I decided to sitema {0,0,0} and gave however when I see the book the author says that it depends wanted to know why since it's all {0,0,0} would you explain me this question?

I know the very basic question, and please do not me so negative pts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the downvote was not because the question is basic but because it is nearly unreadable. I'm guessing that you meant to ask about $\{1+2x^2-x,2-x+3x^2,3-4x+7x^2\}\subset P_2$, but I have no idea what "sitema" is supposed to mean. If the question is what I think it is, then the answer is that your three polynomials are linearly dependent because the second plus the third equals $5$ times the first.  (The statement of the problem includes an attempt to confuse you, because the first of the three polynomials is written with the terms not in standard order.)